# How to set the Pitch in Visual Basic?

Tags: wpf, vb.net, visual-studio

I can change the Rate and Volume, but the tone is no way ..... 
There any way to change it?

This is the code:

```
private void ButtonSpeak_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    if (comboVoice.SelectedItem != null)
    synthesizer.SelectVoice(comboVoice.SelectedItem.ToString());
    synthesizer.Volume = Convert.ToInt32(sliderVolume.Value);
    synthesizer.Rate = Convert.ToInt32(sliderRate.Value);
    switch (synthesizer.State)
    {
            //if synthesizer is ready
        case SynthesizerState.Ready:
            synthesizer.SpeakAsync(ConvertRichTextBoxContentsToString());
            ButtonSpeak.Content = "Pause";
            break;
            //if synthesizer is paused
        case SynthesizerState.Paused:
            synthesizer.Resume();
            ButtonSpeak.Content = "Pause";
            break;
            //if synthesizer is speaking
        case SynthesizerState.Speaking:
            synthesizer.Pause();
            ButtonSpeak.Content = "Resume";
            break;
    }
}
```

Thank you very much for your help!

Comment: Just about no voice implementations actually support it.  Sounding like a chipmunk just isn't considered a useful feature.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not sure about pitch, but if you are using Microsoft System.Speech.Synthesis, you have a VoiceAge property that takes an enum of Adult or Teen, which affects the sound.

```
synth.VoiceAge(Adult);
```

Comment: Thank you very much! But that changes an existing voice or find a voice with those criteria? Excuse my English...

Comment: I think it's used to change an existing voice, but unfortunately it has been a while since I've used speech synthesis!

Comment: Thank you very much @aspiring_expert !